# I installed an app from an untrusted source? What to do now?

Tags: security

As an Ubuntu/Linux newbie, I am not exactly accustomed with security.
I tried to install Gimpshop from this URL: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/gimpshop_2.2.11-1_i386.deb

It was processed by Ubuntu Software Center, but before the end, it disappeared from Ubuntu Software Center and also from my Download folder.

I'm afraid I allowed a virus or something dangerous onto my computer... What can I do now?

Is there a security software I could run to get rid of this? How to know if the package was harmful or not?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: See [How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gimpshop](http://www.gimpshop.com/) is just a little bit modified version of Gimp for Windows and Mac.

On Ubuntu, please just use the plain Gimp which is packaged fine in the main repositories and available straight form the Software Centre.

The package you downloaded appears to be a very blunt single package of Gimp 2.2 (really old!), built in 2006 (!) with all its dependencies in it. The README files reads

> The GNU Image Manipulation Program Version 2.2
>
> This is version 2.2 of The GIMP.

It *looks* harmless by looking at the content.

- It has no install script hooks (`preinst`, `postinst`, etc.) in place. This means it's just a simple unpacking of files.
- The above makes it very clear: it's not responsible for removing the package from your download folder.
- The binaries themselves are hard to check. If you haven't run the program then you don't have to worry about it.
- The quality of the package is really poor and it appears to be built by a very simple "checkinstall" script. This may explain why Software Centre wasn't able to handle it properly.

So, just remove it completely using your package management:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gimpshop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for checking this out and for your advice, Gertvdijk! I wont do the same thing again. Your help is precious, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge gimpshop
```

I have downloaded and analyzed the deb package linked by you, and it looks that it is not harmful.

I don't know why the file disappeared from your Download folder.

Comment: Dear Frantique, Thanks for checking and giving me the process to use in this case. It's making my day! Best, D