# How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?

Tags: security, malware, antivirus, clamav

I installed [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/) via Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) with:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

but how can I scan for viruses?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

### Terminal

At first you have to update the virus definitions with:

```
sudo freshclam
```

Then you can scan for viruses.

```
clamscan OPTIONS File/Folder
```

If necessary start with root permissions: `sudo clamscan`.

**Examples:**

- To check all files on the computer, displaying the name of each file:

  ```
  clamscan -r /
  ```
- To check all files on the computer, but only display infected files and ring a bell when found:

  ```
  clamscan -r --bell -i /
  ```
- To scan all files on the computer but only display infected files when found and have this run in the background:

  ```
  clamscan -r -i / &
  ```

  Note - Display background process's status by running the `jobs` command.
- To check files in the all users home directories:

  ```
  clamscan -r /home
  ```
- To check files in the `USER` home directory and move infected files to another folder:

  ```
  clamscan -r --move=/home/USER/VIRUS /home/USER
  ```
- To check files in the `USER` home directory and remove infected files (**WARNING:** Files are gone.):

  ```
  clamscan -r --remove /home/USER
  ```
- To see more options:

  ```
  clamscan --help
  ```

**See:**

- Latest documentation: [PDF](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/raw/master/manual/clamdoc.pdf) | [HTML](http://www.clamav.net/doc/install.html)
- ClamAV official [Wiki](http://wiki.clamav.net/)
- Ubuntu [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV)

### Graphical User Interface: [ClamTK [image: Install clamtk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clamtk)

[ClamTk](https://launchpad.net/clamtk) is a frontend for ClamAV. You can install it via Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

You can get the latest version from [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads) as Debian package.

There is also a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/clamtk) (Outdated):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:landronimirc/clamtk
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

[image: clamtk screenshot]

**Scan Menu:** Here you can choose a file, folder or a device for scanning

[image: clamtk scan menu screenshot]

**View Menu:**

[image: clamtk view menu screenshot]

**Quarantine Menu:**

[image: clamtk quarantine menu screenshot]

**Advanced Menu:**

[image: clamtk advanced menu screenshot]

**Help Menu:** Here you can check for updates.

[image: clamtk help menu screenshot]

**See:**

- [ClamTk@Sourceforge](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/)
- ClamTk [Help](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/help/)
- ClamTk [FAQ](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: I think it's a mistake to not create at leat man page for clamav, wich is the name of the package.

Comment: If you want to check all files of the system, then you should use `clamscan -r --bell -i --exclude-dir="^/sys" /` because in `/sys/` are no real files and not excluing it would cause reading errors. http://askubuntu.com/questions/591964/clamav-cant-read-file-error

Comment: `sudo freshclam
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).`

Comment: @Dmitriy What has it to do with the answer? It's a specific problem. Maybe you should ask a new question with your detailed problem.

Comment: I commented because this answer seems to not work anymore. At least on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64. Or do you say this issue happens only on my installation?

Comment: @Dmitriy You are probably getting this error because `freshclam` is already running. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/909276/338982

Answer (score 40):

The accepted answer is a great answer, but every time I reach this page, it's a pain to find the command I want from the clutter of information. So just providing a concise answer to the question:

```
sudo apt-get install -y clamav; sudo freshclam
```

To scan all folders in your computer (except `/sys`):

```
clamscan -r -i --exclude-dir="^/sys" --bell /
```

To scan specific folders or files, you have to create a file in which you list out which files/folders you want to scan, and tell clamav where to find that file:

```
clamscan -r -i --bell --file-list=/home/nav/ClamScanTheseFolders.txt
```

My `ClamScanTheseFolders.txt` contained:

```
/media/nav/someFolder1
/media/nav/someFolder2
/opt/someFolder/somefile
```

Comment: Nice. But that should be two dashes before exclude: `--exclude`

Comment: There is still an issue with double dashes before exclude. It does not work after copying and pasting into terminal window

Comment: Does this require a running instance of the clamav-daemon ?

Comment: @SumitKumar No.  clamscan doesn't need the daemon running.  clamdscan does (but is faster because you don't have to load the definitions every time.)