# How do I install Avira?

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, antivirus

I'm new to Ubuntu and want detailed guidance on installing Avira. I read the Manual and did all the procedures but eventually the terminal says to me

```
License has expired at 2012-09-12.
Warning: No dazuko module available, on-access protection disabled.
```

Comment: You don't need an Anti-Virus for Ubuntu. For more information [read this article](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/security).

Comment: Install "BitDefender for Unices". Its too good for removing windows viruses from USB drives.

Comment: Download .deb file, right click on it and choose open with Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: @CuriousApprentice there is no deb file. Download is a TAR.GZ file.

Comment: oh man... I could make an answer but read from 3.3 onwards here: http://www.avira.com/documents/products/pdf/zh-tw/man_avira_antivir-personal_unix_en.pdf I would advice against using this. Use AVG or BitDefende please :X

Comment: I opened the deb version of Avg with Ubuntu Software Center, but it stopped the installation warning about the safety of the package :,( Finally I can't find the deb version of bitdefender or open the only free one I see, with Ubuntu Software Center. sadness (._.)

Comment: If you just want to scan for viruses, you could use [ClamAV](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav).

Comment: Just a reminder: "Discontinuation of Antivirus solutions for Linux systems on June 30th 2016." http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1491

Answer (score 2):

- Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or just search the dash for *Terminal*) and go to the *Downloads* directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

- Download the latest Avira package:

```
wget http://dlpe.antivir.com/package/wks_avira/unix/en/pers/antivir_workstation-pers.tar.gz
```

- Extract the package.

```
tar -xzf antivir_workstation-pers.tar.gz
```

- Go to the extracted directory.

```
cd antivir-workstation-pers-3.1.3.5-0/
```

- Run the `install` file.

```
sudo ./install
```

- Answer the questions as they're asked.

Comment: This might not work: the manual is created with Unix in mind and seems to be valid for Ubuntu <12.04. Both `ia32-libs` and `libstdc++5` seem to be required and probably will not install.

Comment: Thanks all :) , I tried to uninstall and reinstall, but it doesn't make it better :( I read too that maybe my problems with dakuzo depend on the fact that my version (12.10) doesn't allow to install ia32-libs. In general it seems that avira is neglecting unix users (I can't found the page right now but I've read that you can take the key updated from the version for Windows, but than it's better not to allow the automatic update because will gently return to you the old key.)

Comment: Unfortunately the software is not available anymore! Probably [that](http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1491)'s the issue.