# remove TornTV on 12.04LTS and install Clamtk

Tags: 12.04, software-uninstall

I unintentionally got TornTV malware installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 system during torrent transmission.

So, I used `sudo apt-get remove TornTV`,  but the command couldn't locate the TornTV in system, yet it still appears in applications.

Afterwards, I installed Clamtk using http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav, but there is no menu option for scan, view, quarantine etc) in ClamTk window.

[image: blargh]

FYI, I do have wine installed for MS office use only. And I had also tried installing clam from Software Center,that gave the same results.

Any help on removal of TornTV will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance, all.!

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove TornTV` may not work if the program name is "torntv", for example, and not TornTV. Check the case (and spelling) when using the terminal.

Comment: "Torntv" is a piece of malware and isn't an Ubuntu package, so can't be removed using `apt-get` (according to `synaptic` there are no similar package names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `dpkg -l | grep -i torntv` in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to find the exact name and location of the package.

I'm guessing TornTV installed in your Wine environment, so you can try to uninstall it with "Uninstall Wine Software", which can be found by Search in the menu.

Comment: You gave me the simplest answer, I removed the TornTV from uninstall wine software. Thank you @Smart69.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as mentioned in my comment above, TornTV is not an Ubuntu package, and so can't be removed with the `apt-get remove` command.

In order to scan using `clamtk`, you need to do the following. First, update your virus definitions with the command `sudo freshclam`. Then, start up `clamtk` (you can set this to automatically update definitions from the Advanced-> Rerun antivirus setup menu, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

From the UI you have a number of options. First, under "Preferences", you can choose more detailed options as to how it should scan -- whether it should scan hidden files/folders (those beginning with a dot), whether it should scan large files, etc.

In the screenshot you posted, you can click "Home" to scan your entire home directory (`~/`, or `/home/[username]`). Alternatively, you can tell it to scan a specific folder under the "scan" menu (this will appear at the top of your screen when you mouse over it, as in this screenshot):

[image: Using ClamTK to scan a directory]
Then just choose the directory you want to scan. If you want to scan the entire partition I assume you will need to have the "Scan all files and directories" option checked, and possibly will need to be running clamtk as `sudo`, but I am not fully certain of this.

Hope this is some help.

Comment: I can't believe that after spending almost a year on ubuntu, I missed hovering the cursor on top of screen. I am grateful for your detailed answer.