# Is it a good idea to scan external HDD with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, antivirus, malware

I have an external hard disk drive, and it may have some viruses in it.

I don't want to connect it to Windows, so when I have to copy something from it, I do it in Ubuntu.

Now I have to install a lot of -Windows- programs from it, so does it make sense to install an antivirus (like BitDefender) and scan from Ubuntu?

I mean, does just plugging it into Windows puts me in danger?

Can there be viruses in Autorun.exe or such?

And which free antivirus should I use?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not asking about Ubuntu viruses. I'm asking about Windows viruses, and using Ubuntu as a "weapon" against them.

Comment: I don't know the difference between Ubuntu viruses and Windows viruses.

Comment: Me, neither. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: The difference is that linux viruses, by and large, do not exist.  The only really "in the wild" stuff is junk from anti-freedom-of-speech companies that sell snooping products to repressive regimes.  Think FinFisher - linux version.

Comment: OK, thanks but I'm interested in removing **Windows Viruses**.

Comment: Then your question falls under the duplicate.

Comment: The answers suit your question.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw check this one [..:: How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV? ::..](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this many times.  Have taken infected drives out of a physical computer and hooked them up to my Windows machine to clean the HDD.  As long as Antivirus application on your Windows machine is up to date you should be fine.  Before you access the external drive run a scan on it.  I would suggest both antivirus (I prefer AVG) and MalwareBytes.

Comment: Thanks! So you are sure that just plugging the HDD will **not** infect viruses?

Comment: I have never had that happen.  But if you start browsing around and clicking on files on the external drive it may not be good.  But again like I said as long as your Windows machine has an up to date antivirus app on it you should be fine.

Comment: I'm not guaranteeing anything.  But my experience has never got my Windows machine infected.