# Online virus scanners for linux

Tags: antivirus

Can we scan the drive online to scan and remove the virus files?

If there where can i find them? How to scan and remove the virus through online scanners?

Thank you!

Comment: Most Linux users are not likely to trust an online app to run through their file system for any purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There is No online antivirus for linux.

click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/10373) and see why do you need an antivirus for ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

If you need to scan only few files, you can use [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com).

However, in case of scanning the entire Windows drive (as you mentioned), I would try different solutions:

- try to install [ClamAV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav). Even in case of the Live distribution you should be able to install software (obviously it will be not available after computer restart)
- try to search for [Antivirus Rescue CDs](http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/). They will include antivirus software which runs directly from bootable CD

Comment: I would recommend caution with ClamAV. On a dual-boot with 12.04 and Windows, ClamAV was too zealous and messed up my Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Clam antivirus is useless for cleaning a windows PC, or the windows partition of a dual-boot linux/windows PC, or a virtual OS, or running windows via Wine - because - the scan literally takes at least 12-24hrs - and it finds THOUSANDS of potentially infected files - which requires you to go through ALL of them, one at a time, and double check each file online - one at a time - it's completely useless.

If I, or members of the general public, could DO that - I/we wouldnt NEED an antivirus scanner/cleaner program - we would simply go through our windows partition manually and delete the infected files & registry entries.

I have yet to find a user-friendly, USEFUL antivirus that you can use Linus to disinfect a windows PC.. apparently no one thinks they will get PAID if you can do it yourself.