# ClamAV: Can't read file ERROR

Tags: antivirus, clamav

When running the command today:

```
sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua / > clamscan1.txt
```

I got very many errors going along the lines of these ones (in the `txt` file):

```
/sys/fs/ecryptfs/version: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/inode_readahead_blks: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_max_to_scan: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/msg_ratelimit_burst: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/delayed_allocation_blocks: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/max_writeback_mb_bump: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_stream_req: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_min_to_scan: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_stats: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/err_ratelimit_burst: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/session_write_kbytes: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/lifetime_write_kbytes: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_group_prealloc: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/inode_goal: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/reserved_clusters: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/extent_max_zeroout_kb: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/err_ratelimit_interval_ms: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/warning_ratelimit_burst: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/warning_ratelimit_interval_ms: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/mb_order2_req: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/sda1/msg_ratelimit_interval_ms: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/features/meta_bg_resize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/features/batched_discard: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/fs/ext4/features/lazy_itable_init: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/taint: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/initstate: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/coresize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.init.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.smp_locks: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.data: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/__mcount_loc: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.rodata: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/__verbose: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.strtab: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.symtab: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.gnu.linkonce.this_module: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.rodata.str1.1: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.rodata.str1.8: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.note.gnu.build-id: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.exit.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/sections/.data..read_mostly: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/refcnt: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/initsize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/taint: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/initstate: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/coresize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.init.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.smp_locks: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.data: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/__param: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/__mcount_loc: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.rodata: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/__verbose: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.strtab: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.symtab: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.gnu.linkonce.this_module: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.rodata.str1.1: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.rodata.str1.8: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.note.gnu.build-id: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.exit.text: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/sections/.data..read_mostly: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/parameters/hashsize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/refcnt: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/initsize: Can't read file ERROR
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/srcversion: Can't read file ERROR
```

And in the Terminal window I got lots of errors such as these ones:

```
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/videobuf2_memops/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4092 bytes @ offset 4, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/keyboard/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/kgdb_nmi/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/virtio_mmio/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/xhci_hcd/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/6lowpan_iphc/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/ip6_tables/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/xt_addrtype/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/pci_hotplug/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/ip6t_REJECT/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/x86_pkg_temp_thermal/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/debug_core/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/snd_seq_midi/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/crc32_pclmul/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4089 bytes @ offset 7, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4092 bytes @ offset 4, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4092 bytes @ offset 4, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/psmouse/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @ offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv6/uevent: Permission denied
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
```

Is this anything to worry about?

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Package Information:

```
clamav:
  Installed: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Candidate: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.98.4+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`/sys` is the mount point of a [sysfs virtual file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs):

> **sysfs** is a virtual file system provided by the Linux kernel. By using virtual files, sysfs exports information about various kernel
>   subsystems, hardware devices and associated device drivers from the
>   kernel's device model to user space. In addition to providing
>   information about various devices and kernel subsystems, exported
>   virtual files are also used for their configuring.

The files in `/sys` are not real files, viruses will not infect them. Also, you can't create new files inside `/sys`, try it yourself! There's no need to scan it. Use the command line option `--exclude-dir="^/sys"` to ignore `/sys`.

Comment: its like? clamscan -r --bell -i --exclude-dir="^/sys" /