# Anti virus scan with ClamTK

Tags: 18.04, antivirus, clamav, clamtk

I just started using Ubuntu 18.04.1 version and two days ago , I received an email from trusted source with 2 attachments and I downloaded those files on my desktop, files were encrypted and were asking me to sign in with my passwords to open, I tried to open those files as well. Later on I found out that sender's server was hacked and that email was from hackers.

Then I installed ClamTK anti virus and run scan today and found out below results. These are just a small sample, I have hundreds of these output in my terminal. What is this? is this normal or its a virus?  many thanks

```
    LibClamAV Error: fmap_readpage: pread error: Input/output error

    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4087 bytes @ offset 9, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4087 bytes @ offset 9, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4088 bytes @ offset 8, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4075 bytes @ offset 21, got 0
    LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4074 bytes @ offset 22, got 0

LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4095 bytes @ offset 1, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @ offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4093 bytes @ offset 3, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4089 bytes @ offset 7, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @ offset 5, got 0

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6762421
Engine version: 0.100.2
Scanned directories: 59238
Scanned files: 337081
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 23210
Data scanned: 9843.74 MB
Data read: 15217.11 MB (ratio 0.65:1)
Time: 1794.555 sec (29 m 54 s)
```

Comment: I done some online research and it suggests that these are not viruses but clamav trying to read a directory which it is not allowed. Is it right? 

what is known viruses in scan summary ?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to extend it, don’t use comments for that. What type did the files have? I doubt a random email virus would infect an up-to-date Ubuntu installation, they are mostly intended for Windows. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591964/clamav-cant-read-file-error

Comment: Known viruses refers to the number of viruses in the clamav signature database (ie. viruses that it can scan for or knows about).

ClamAV scanned 337081 files in your 59238 directories & found 0 infected files (using the 6752421 viruses it knows about that were looked for) This is a good result :)   Sorry I use `clamav` to scan windows computers on occasion, but don't recall seeing your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known viruses refers to the number of viruses in the clamav signature database (ie. viruses that it can scan for or knows about).

ClamAV scanned *337081* files in your *59238* directories & found *0* infected files (using the *6752421* viruses it knows about that were looked for)   This is a good result :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback, it helps my peace of mind.