# Problem with Comodo Installation

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, antivirus, administrator

After installing Comodo, though logged in as adminstrator, tried to run `/opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh` and it says

```
Please run this script with adminstrative priviledges
```

even though I am logged in as an adminstrator.  This was downloaded on the Ubuntu Software Center and I have Ubuntu 14.04. So now I have a GUI that seems to work but a panel to the left with file system filter driver not loaded - run diagnostics. I run them, try to type the command line in the gnome terminal and same error occurs. So frustrating!

Comment: Ubuntu dosnt log in as root by default - did you try typing `sudo` before the command?

Comment: Just found a page saying I should've typed sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh  and then the terminal run through the lines sucessfuly and says COMODO installed sucessfully. Yet when I open COMODO  I still still the left panel saying File System Filter Driver Not Loaded. Once again I hit the Run Diagnostics button and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

> tried to run /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh and it says "Please run this
> script with adminstrative priviledges even though I am logged in as an
> adminstrator.

Please note that, even you logged in with your admin user as you say this means nothing in Linux, even you have admin privileges, you in really not using those privileges and in really system treats you as a normal user UNLESS you use sudo or su to root.

There are two ways to run administrative applications in Linux. You can either switch to the super user (root) with the su command, or you can take advantage of sudo.

[Read this introduction to SUDO](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo).

#### Back to your question

> Please run this script with adminstrative priviledges

Then you need to call your script using `sudo`:

```
 sudo ./opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh
```

> File System Filter Driver Not Loaded.

Refer to [this post in the Comodo forum](http://forums.comodo.com/comodo-antivirus-for-linux-cavl-b275.0/-t105780.0.html)

guys there are talking about some patch or some other fixes which may be not valid!!!

---

I advise you to try some other antivirus tools, you can check available from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus.

Personally I like [ClamAV](http://ClamAV). Here full nice tutorial [How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav)