# What are the best antivirus soloutions for scannining USB drives for Malyware and Viruses?

Tags: windows, antivirus

I have an old Win XP computer that was made in 2001 that can't connect to the internet and has no anti virus. Still works fine but I am wondering what the best way is to scan USB drives and files in Ubuntu for Windows Viruses and Malware before I connect them to the computer. I have tried a Windows alternative using `wine` but I had to reload Ubuntu trying to uninstall it.

So how can I scan for Windows malware using Ubuntu?

Comment: See also: "[How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](http://askubuntu.com/q/250290/38585)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ClamAV - this AntiVirus and AntiMalware tool is available in the Ubuntu repositories.

[ClamAV® is an open source antivirus engine for detecting trojans, viruses, malware & other malicious threats.](http://www.clamav.net/)

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk clamtk-nautilus
```

**`clamav`** is the anti-virus toolkit.
**`clamtk`** is the graphical front-end, a graphical user interface for **`clamav`**.
**`clamtk-nautilus`** is a Nautilus file manager plugin to allow
right-click support for scanning.

Comment: ClamAv produces false positives.