# ClamAV only scans one directory. What should I do?

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav

I was scanning my PC with ClamAV earlier today, only to find out that it only scanned one directory.

Here is what it said:

```
joshua@joshua-LIFEBOOK-S6x20:~ > sudo clamscan /
/initrd.img: Symbolic link
/vmlinuz: Symbolic link

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4287121
Engine version: 0.98.7
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 27.298 sec (0 m 27 s)
```

I did `sudo freshclam` and all it said is that I had an older version (0.98.7) and that I should upgrade to 0.99.1.

What should I do?

Comment: a better question is what are you trying to do with clamscan ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`-r`** in the option field : i.e, **`clamscan -r directory-name`**

```
-r, --recursive
              Scan  directories  recursively.  All  the  subdirectories in the
              given directory will be scanned.
```