# I can't figure out how to update clamav OR run it

Tags: clamav

I just installed clamav, but it says it's out of date and to read some page full of gobbledygook to learn how to upgrade it.  Gobbledygook isn't telling me anything.  Then it says a whole bunch of stuff is up to date.  Not clear if that means clamav is still outdated.

Then when I run it again it's still outdated.

Please tell me EN INGLIS, POR FAVOR, the exact commands to actually update my clamav software, my exact commands to update my definitions, and then, my exact commands to RUN it, now and not whenever.   Settings tells me it's set to run at 0000000000000 whatevers and I want to run it right now, and I don't see something to click to do that!

and I want to run it right now and not 000000000000000000000000000 whatevers too!

And pages written in gobbledygook are NOT helpful!

Thanks!

Yours,
Dora Smith

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

Comment: If you cannont bring yourself to read (and re-read) on-line documentation to gain understanding, how can we know that you'll read what we say? Since AskUbuntu is entirely volunteer-driven site, whining about "I want to run it right now", and demanding English responses in poor Spanish ("EN INGLIS, POR FAVOR") (Did you mean: "EN INGLÉS, POR FAVOR"?) on an english web site don't motivate me to help you.

Comment: That page had actual useful information - it's the first I've heard of the command clamscan.

Comment: But the instructions on that page are bad.   Specifically, it downloads the out of date version that is on Ubuntu's software, which is what caused the error messages I keep getting to begin with.

Comment: Is there a way to enter more than one paragraph on this thing?

Comment: The informaiton I asked for is here.   Allinoneparagraphofcourse.  https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav-on-unix-linux-macos-from-source     It is necessary to scroll down to find the instructions.  WAY too complicated, but it is clearly written.  And once I got done it can only download four of the five databases, three of which aren't on the list of ones Ubuntu downloads from the Ubuntu version of the instructions that install the out of date version.

Comment: if you're not handy with the terminal look at the answer from *heynnema* to do it GUI way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ow do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/)

Answer (score 4):

The main clamav engine is always outdated. Eventually it'll be replaced by a newer version, but only to be outdated again. Don't worry about that.

Install `ClamTk` which is a GUI to the clamav software. Once you've installed it from the Ubuntu repos, go directly to the author's web site at https://gitlab.com/dave_m/clamtk/wikis/Home and get the latest version.

From the `ClamTk` GUI, you can update the definitions files, schedule updates, and schedule scans.

[image]