# pmproxy using 100% CPU

Tags: malware, cpu-load

For a couple days now, I notice a process called pmproxy using 100% CPU on bootup and stays at 100%. I kill the process and it restarts a couple seconds later. I renamed the folder /usr/lib/pcp and that got it to stop restarting.

I don't remember installing or downloading anything like that. Is it malicious?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with latest updates.

Comment: I'd [run a malware scan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav) and see what turns up. I'm not familiar with that pmproxy, but something that uses 100% CPU and auto restarts is certainly suspicious at best. I'd run a malware scan, and if it does turn out to be malware, **have an offsite _isolated_ backup of anything important** if you don't already

Comment: The `pmproxy` package is for [performance metrics collection](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pmproxy.1.html) and is installed as part of the Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) toolkit. If your machine is a VPS, then it was likely installed as part of the base installation package from the provider. There may be a reason for the CPU consumption recorded in the `/var/log/syslog` file, so you'll want to check in there to see what might have triggered the issue 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to `cockpit-pcp` removing both resolved the issue for me (as cockpit-pcp is not important for me on my laptop)

`sudo apt remove pcp`