# How to remove Virus Popup Alerts coming from Chrome?

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, malware, antivirus, popup-ads

I have downloaded a PDF book from a site after which every now and then this virus alert pops up as shown in the Image.

[image: Virus alert Pop up]

[image: Virus alert Pop Up]

How to get rid of it? Please suggest any Antivirus which disinfect the virus and does not delete infected file/folder and its installation steps. I have recently subscribed to (22.04) Ubuntu-Pro.

I do not want any of my folder/file gets deleted while Antivirus scanning. (For example Avast on Windows deletes files/folder.)

I read about some of the linux Antiviruses but since I do not want to take *"Risk"* about it. Hence I posted here to seek help.

I tried using ClamAV but still no use.

For **experts** you can reproduce this issue by downloading PDFs from http://libgen.rs/search.php

Comment: Does the book actually contain a virus? If it does, you want it deleted. If it doesn't, don't worry. If you got it from a sketchy site, there's a good chance that it does.

Comment: Aside from that, McAfee doesn't support Linux anymore. Did you install it, or is it just an alert faking McAfee?

Comment: @Esther : Thanks for responding. All the PDFs are readable and doesn't look like they contain any Viruses. Although before downloading an privacy window appeared stating " This connection is not safe" but since this is Linux I ignored it. 

I did not install any Antivirus yet. You are right, this seems an alert faking McAfee. Getting similar alerts sometime not mentioning McAfee.

Comment: it sounds like you might have an actual virus which is faking McAfee, then. There are antiviruses for Linux, like ClamAV and others. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav?rq=1) is a Q&A about using ClamAV from Terminal and GUI

Comment: you can also check running processes for anything that looks virus-like or that you don't recognize, and ask about it here (or [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1503653/edit) your question to add that info).

Comment: Sure, I don't know how to recognise if its a Virus related process / system related process. I will check it using ```htop``` . If I found something I will edit my Question.

Comment: You said you never installed an antivirus, so anything that looks antivirus-like is probably an actual virus. Otherwise, look for anything with a suspicious name (other than "tracker" or similar, which, despite looking suspicious, is actually a legitimate process)

Comment: @Esther : I tried ClamAV but no use. I also tried to search in htop but I am not able to decide whether which sercive is responcible for the Pop up.

Comment: @PVD It looks like you allowed, in your browser, notifications for a website that is sending annoying messages. Try clearing your browsing data

Comment: @DanielT : Thank you Sir for your response. I was able to resolve this issue after I watched some youTube videos. But this forum is my first place to go hence I asked my Query here and tried to solve it with a different direction. What I tried is the same solution provided by you. Just I couldn't trace it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought of this Virus Popups as if they are some system related viruses which entered into my system as they also appeared when I am on my Desktop or browsing folders . After trying ClamAV which did not able to remove this virus popup, I checked this YouTube video by Geek Stuff https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0XvO1uPJrc&t=214s .

You can disable/remove/block this popups under chorme -> Settings -> Serch for Notifications -> Not allowed to send notification as shown in the Image.

[image: Chrome Virus Popup]